# Malloc error when assigning memory to a struct

Tags: c, dev-c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct Node{
    int number;
    struct Node * next;
};

struct Node * insertNodeInLinkedList(int number,struct Node * startOfList){
    if(startOfList == NULL){
        startOfList = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        startOfList->number = number;
        startOfList->next = NULL;
    }else{
        struct Node * temporaryNode = startOfList;
        struct Node * newNode = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        while(temporaryNode->next != NULL){
            temporaryNode = temporaryNode->next;
        }

        newNode->number = number;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        temporaryNode->next = newNode;

    }
    return startOfList;
}

void display(struct Node * startOfList){
    struct Node * temporaryNode = startOfList;
    while(temporaryNode != NULL){
        printf("%d",temporaryNode->number);
        temporaryNode = temporaryNode->next;
    }   
}

int main (void){
    int howManyNodes = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int enteredNumber = 0;
    struct Node * startOfMyList = NULL;

    printf("How many nodes do you want in your linked list?");
    scanf("%d",&howManyNodes);

    while(counter < howManyNodes){
        printf("Enter number: ");
        scanf("%d",&enteredNumber);
        startOfMyList = insertNodeIntoLinkedList(enteredNumber,startOfMyList);
        counter++;
    }
    display(startOfMyList);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

This is my simple program to insert and display nodes of a linked list. However, the line:

```
startOfList = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

gets flagged as an error. I do not know why.

What is going wrong here ?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth oh the error changed now and I get `E:\DevCProjects\DataStructures\SingleLinkedList.o SingleLinkedList.c:(.text+0x12d): undefined reference to `insertNodeIntoLinkedList'`

Comment: Do you have a function called `insertNodeIntoLinkedList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `malloc` seems to be correct.

For your new error it is simply because in `main` you are calling `insertNodeIntoLinkedList` and you define the function before:

```
insertNodeInLinkedList
//        ^^
```

Also, you need to include `<stdlib.h>` for the [`malloc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html) function.

Comment: ouch ! That was very clumsy of me. I also have this warning `13 32 E:\DevCProjects\DataStructures\SingleLinkedList.c [Warning] incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'malloc' [enabled by default]` why is that ?

Comment: @LittleChild You need to include `<stdlib.h>`

Comment: Sorry for such a dumb question. I do not code in C. I am doing this as a part of my assignment :)

Comment: @LittleChild Not a problem :)